# EvoHtmlToPdf - gap between item and number in auto generated table of content

Tags: tableofcontents, evopdf

I am trying to create lines between items and numbers in a table of contents generated automatically by EVO HTML to Pdf. My current approach is via CSS and the TableOfContentsOptions:

```
converter.TableOfContentsOptions.SetItemStyle(1, "border-bottom:1px solid #000000)
```

and

```
converter.TableOfContentsOptions.SetPageNumberStyle(1, "border-bottom:1px solid #000000)
```

The result looks pretty good. However, there is a gap between item and number which unfortunately bothers our customers...

[image]

Is there a way to close the gap?

(EVO HTML to PDF version 9.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EvoHtmlToPdfs table of contents is indeed a "real" HTML table:

[image]

Using CSS, you can hide the 3rd-last column:

```
    converter.TableOfContentsOptions.GlobalStyle = 
            """
                td:nth-last-child(3){
                    display:None;
                }
            """
```